# Vim JSDoc, PHPDoc, JavaDoc, RDoc info

Tags: vim, phpdoc, rdoc, jsdoc, perldoc

Here is the deal,

If you've used Aptana, Eclipse or even Microsoft Expression Web editor, then you've seen that  they feature a **Balloon Text** or **Intellisense popup** showing hints/info of built-in and custom objects, methods, etc.

They get the info thru JSDoc, PHPDoc, JavaDoc, RDoc, etc.

I'd like to get these feature in Vim, maybe implemented as omnicompletion and also since Mac/GVim supports balloon text, as this as well.

Answer (score 2):

This feature actually exists and is defined in each file type's Omni-completion. For example, enabling PHP's omni-completion will show completions in a popup window as well as the method definition in a smaller buffer which opens at the top of the current tab-frame.

Activate it by adding the following to your .vimrc

```
filetype plugin on
au FileType php set omnifunc=phpcomplete#CompletePHP
```

And then using C-x C-o for completion. (I find many people like to remap this to C-space to mimic Visual Studio)

More information and links about omnicompletion can be found at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion

Comment: I'm well aware of the builtin omnicompletion for vim, but this is what I want, a balloon hint for custom objects documented as PHPdoc, etc. just like in the first outline of this blog post http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code/

Comment: BTW, you may wanna look at neocomplcache vim plugin, it makes the omnicompletion a lot "smarter" and automatically shows the popup